# Google sheets conditional formatting

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to format cell based on cell to left side. What I want to do is, when cell to left side is not empty and lower than today's date then format.

```
=and(
TODAY()>INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW();COLUMN()-1))),
not(isblank(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW();COLUMN()-1)))))  
)
```

But google sheets doesn't accept this function. The question is, why?

Answer (score 0):

Try just referencing the cell to the left. Put this in B1 to check the dates in A1:

Apply to range B1:B

Custom formula is

```
=and(TODAY()>A1,not (isblank(A1)))
```

If you want to use indirect, this will work:

```
=and(TODAY()>INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW();COLUMN()-1)),not(isblank(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW();COLUMN()-1)))))
```